When installing Mastodon, the Rails container cannot find the database on postgres
I am having issues with database connection when running mastodon in a docker container.
During the setup process, I set up a mastodon user and gave them permission to create a database.
During the setup process, the database setup works, and the process finishes.
When I do a docker compose up, I get the following error:
db-1         | 2024-04-10 21:06:52.764 UTC [29] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mastodon"
db-1         | 2024-04-10 21:06:52.764 UTC [29] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"

and
web-1        | /opt/mastodon/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:81:in `rescue in new_client': We could not find your database: mastodon. Which can be found in the database configuration file located at config/database.yml. (ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError)
web-1        |
web-1        | To resolve this issue:
web-1        |
web-1        | - Did you create the database for this app, or delete it? You may need to create your database.
web-1        | - Has the database name changed? Check your database.yml config has the correct database name.
web-1        |
web-1        | To create your database, run:
web-1        |
web-1        |         bin/rails db:create

Connecting to DB container shows that the database and user do exist.
The password I used when creating the user is the same as the one in .env.production
The db part of my docker-container looks like
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    shm_size: 256mb
    networks:
      - internal_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'pg_isready', '-U', 'postgres']
    volumes:
      - ./postgres14:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust'

Any ideas?
Thanks!
